# To find element based on grandchildren tags using elementtree

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml, elementtree

I'm completely new to xml parsing .I have some thousands of xml's and I want to find out all element **DE** , only when I have **country** tag

Here is my sample xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DE>
   <CT>
      <IG>
         <FS id="01">
            <FE id="A" fId="B">
               <title>Apple</title>
            </FE>
         </FS>
         <country syse="21" subSys="2">
            <FF FR="101" fe="01" />
            <referTo refType="t06">
               <CF Code="350" />
            </referTo>
            <place id="00A" placeValue="00AB">
               <Q>001</Q>
               <TQ>0001</TQ>
               <PR Value="A" CodeValue="C" />
            </place>
            <place id="00E" placeValue="00EF">
               <Q>001</Q>
               <TQ>0001</TQ>
               <PR Value="03" AValue="957" />
               <Books>
                  <IA>
                     <Part />
                  </IA>
                  <PRGroup>
                     <country Code="5">
                        <PR Value="02" AValue="345" />
                        <constrain>Double condition.</constrain>
                        <constrain>Double condition.</constrain>
                     </country>
                  </PRGroup>
               </Books>
            </place>
         </country>
      </IG>
   </CT>
</DE>
```

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(content)
root = tree.getroot()
Num = root.findall("//DE[//place/Books/PRGroup/country]")
```

am getting predicate error or absolute path error when am trying different ways but am not able to figure this out.
How can I retrieve the results and access the attributes based on that
could you please help me on this.

Comment: It's simpler if you use lxml instead of elementtree.

Comment: @JackFleeting Could you give me in lxml , so that I will change the code accordingly

Comment: Sure; see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With lxml it should be something along these lines:

```
from lxml import etree
content = """[your xml above]"""
root = etree.fromstring(content.encode())
Num = root.xpath("//DE[//place/Books/PRGroup/country]")
```